# Can't boot anyting from USB

Tags: boot, usb

Somebody gave me a Packard bell ENME69BP with ChromiumOS installed on it so I wanted to change the OS.

There's not any option for Legacy boot on the bios (insydeh20 v2.07)

I tried to boot multiple OS (Windows 7, 10, Ubuntu) from different USB but none seems to work. They're not on boot menu, secure boot is disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a "Bay Trail". The Bay Trail UEFI never had "legacy", never will and it isn't needed. Now, for starters - and because of the *horrible* Bay Trail - forget about Ubuntu or any other Linux or Windows 7. Windows 10 *may* work but you have to use the official Microsoft tool to make a bootable Windows 10 USB media.